# Linux Pacemaker: Resource showing as "unrunnable start (blocked)" has been created

Tags: linux, nfs, sles, pacemaker, high-availability

We are using SLES 12 SP4

We have observed few things from the today testing.   Following are the steps:

**Step 1**: When we create kernel panic (on Node01) with the command “**echo 'b' > /proc/sysrq-trigger**”  or “**echo 'c' > /proc/sysrq-trigger**” on the node where the resources are running, then the cluster detecting the change but unable to start any resources (except SBD) on other active node.

**Step 2**: As per the logs we can find the following  errors:

```
pengine:     info: LogActions:       Leave      stonith-sbd           (Started node02)
pengine:   notice: LogAction:      * Start      pri-javaiq            (node02 )   due to unrunnable nfs_filesystem start (blocked)
pengine:   notice: LogAction:      * Start      lb_health_probe       (node02 )   due to unrunnable nfs_filesystem start (blocked)
pengine:   notice: LogAction:      * Start      pri-ip_vip            (node02 )   due to unrunnable nfs_filesystem start (blocked)
pengine:   notice: LogAction:      * Start      nfs_filesystem        (node02 )   blocked
```

**Step 3**: But when we execute “init 6” on the node (on which we have created ‘kernel panic’), surprisingly  the resources on other node are starting and running successfully.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you don't have a watchdog setup or configured properly.

SBD fencing only works because of two parts. Firstly, the "poison-pill" passed to the misbehaving node via the shared storage, and the watchdog that would reboot the nodes should SBD fail, and the node not be able to "suicide".

It sounds like you're crashing/panicing the node, so it can't possibly fence itself at that point, and we'd have to rely on the watchdog to reboot the system. This also would explain why it then behaves as you would expect when you run init 6, as you've effectively done manually what a watchdog would have done.

SuSE has excellent documentation SBD fencing, including explanation on why watchdog is required, and how to configure it. https://documentation.suse.com/sle-ha/15-SP1/html/SLE-HA-all/cha-ha-storage-protect.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we found cause. This is because, the pacemaker service is enabled at startup. No issues now once we disabled the pacemaker service.